4,4,2,6,2,10,4,_ sequence from 4th grade packet
The sequence (from my child's "for fun" challenge packet, not for credit or graded) is:

4,4,2,6,2,10,4,_

The possible answers are:

A) 15
B) 20
C) 25
D) 28



jmcarson sure has an impressive beard for a 4th grader. :^)


I am the parent. It is a “for fun” challenge packet, not for credit or graded or anything :)

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Is this US 4th grade, meaning the kid is 6+4=10 yo? If so this is an impressive "for fun" assignement.

I think the answer is

 D) 28

Reason

 With the original sequence if you divide each odd term with its next adjacent even term you get 1/1 (4/4), 1/3 (2/6), 1/5 (2/10) where the denominator increases by 2 each time and so 28 is the answer as it is the only one that makes 4/28 which is 1/7, fitting in the pattern established. You could conversely divide each even term with the odd term before it making 1,3,5,7 from another perspective.


I don't think denominator increases by 2 each time edit: nvm i get it now

Same answer as PDT, just explained differently:

 


this is a better explanation of what is going on! I just stopped thinking about the sequence once I spotted the division pattern. Nice spot though! +1

@PDT: Better is in the eye of the beholder. It's always bugged me that for the sequences puzzles there's always many different explanations, and while the "simpler" is likely "better", guessing what the asker might have thought of is such an open-ended question :'(

This also explains why it doesn't start "2, 2"

I'd actually go so far as to say this should be the accepted answer. If @PDT's explanation was all there was to it, the ninth number could really be anything. Also, this exhibits the underlying 1,2,3,... sequence. (No offense!)

@Oliphaunt you don’t need to know what the 9th number is in the question

Congrats on earning your gold Populist badge! Great way to explain the pattern behind this sequence clearly and concisely, well deserved.

@Stiv Thanks!  I was surprised and pleased to get a gold badge; I know they are rarely awarded.

Fun fact (not for 4th graders): suppose we change the first term from $4$ to $x$. Then if $x > 1 + \sqrt{2\pi e} \operatorname{erf}(\frac{\sqrt2}{2})$, the sequence diverges to $+\infty$, and if $x < 1 + \sqrt{2\pi e} \operatorname{erf}(\frac{\sqrt2}{2})$, the sequence diverges to $-\infty$. (This threshold is approximately $3.82137$.)

If you continue the terms to the left (negative) then the numbers stop being integers :)
